# Request larger than allowed

Tags: docker, serverless, openwhisk

I have an OpenWhisk deployment and I am using docker. I want to increase max memory limit. I think it can be done with enviroment variables. Which enviroment variable can I use to fix my problem?

I get the following error.
`Request larger than allowed: 3600245 > 1048576 bytes. (code 9RKHKJtJVqWK7jz3o608HcQagzLHFfvt)`

Comment: What image is it you are running?

Comment: One of the 2 I am not sure   ----------------openwhisk/action-nodejs-v14   ----or------       
openwhisk/java8action